# how to delete records from several child tables in the same query

Tags: mysql, sql-delete, cascading-deletes

I ve got a database modelize like this,
One mother table let's call it table_mother, and severals child tables.
Relation beetween table_mother and childs is like this:

All tables childs have a foreign key kind of name as the id of the mother table (id_table_mother) (relationship is 1->n as id_table_mother is uniq and tbale child can get several entries for id_table_mother)

I would like to delete all records in childs table wich are related no more with the mother table, for now i try something like this

```
           DELETE FROM tb_child_1,tb_child_2,tb_child_3
              WHERE 
tb_child_1.id_table_mother 
AND tb_child_2.id_table_mother 
AND tb_child_3.id_table_mother
              NOT IN (SELECT id_table_mother FROM tb_table_mother);
```

Thx

edit : this is how I ended for now

```
delete from tb_child_1 where id_mother not in (select id_mother from tb_mother_table);
delete from tb_child_2 where id_mother not in (select id_mother from tb_mother_table);
```

any "global" solution ?
also my database is not innodb so I can 't go with foreigh keys and stuff

Comment: you can make use of cascading triggers here is a helpful linkhttp://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/idshelp/v10/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.sqls.doc/sqls362.htm see if it helps

Comment: sry can't reach that page (not found)

Comment: http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/idshelp/v10/index.jsp?topic=/com.ib‌​m.sqls.doc/sqls362.htm Copy and paste this in your browsers address bar

Answer (score 1):

You have to build FOREIGN KEY Constraints to be performed on delete or update to know more about FOREIGN KEY Constraints visit http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html

Comment: yes but my db is not innodb compliant (I didn't make it , it s something I retrieve ), the foreign keys are set but not as innodb charts...

Answer (score 0):

Write 3 queries like this one -

```
DELETE
  tb_child_1
FROM
  tb_table_mother
LEFT JOIN
  tb_child_1
   ON tb_table_mother.id_table_mother = tb_child_1.id_table_mother
WHERE
   tb_child_1.id_table_mother IS NULL;
```